# get lat and long from all firebase documents

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase, react-native-maps

[image]I am trying to get location from all documents of my collection, but in this way I am getting just one document lat and long.

I need to get all lat and long data from all documents and show it in my map

what I am doing wrong??

can anyone help me with it??

POINTS STATE:

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState([]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getProviderLocation() {
      try {
        const db = firestore();

        await db
          .collection('Providers')
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.empty) {
              console.log('nao tem');
              return;
            }
            console.log('docss', snapshot.docs);
            snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
              // console.log('ID', doc.id);
              setPoints([
                ...points,
                {
                  id: doc.id,
                  latitude: doc.data().address.latitude,
                  longitude: doc.data().address.longitude,
                },
              ]);

              console.log('points', points);

            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    if (coordinates) getProviderLocation();
  }, []);
```

RENDERING:

```
{points.map(point => (
              <Marker
                onPress={() => navigateToCreateAppointment(point.id)}
                style={styles.mapMarkerImage}
                key={point.id}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: parseFloat(point.latitude),
                  longitude: parseFloat(point.longitude),
                  latitudeDelta: 0.015,
                  longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
                }}
              >
                <Image source={wingImg} />
              </Marker>
            ))}
```

Comment: What is being printed on console?

Comment: @frunkad 
in points i have an array with repeated objects obtaining the lat and log of two documents because i have only two documents in firebase.

but I have the same two documents repeated I Wll add an image example

Comment: @frunkad Look at my image please

Comment: Can you change their IDs?

Comment: in this case is the same document

Comment: the ID is generated automatic from firebase